# facebook application redirects to redirect_uri location

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Let me put my code first
     string strSigned = Request.Params["signed_request"];
               // JSONObject obj = JSONObject.CreateFromString(strSigned);

```
            Facebook.FacebookSignedRequest fb = FacebookSignedRequest.Parse(AppSecret, strSigned);

            JsonObject jsonObj = fb.Data as JsonObject;

            if (!jsonObj.ContainsKey("user_id"))
            {
                string appId = App_Id;


                string redirectUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/Default.aspx"

                string redirectstr = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + appId + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUrl + "&scope=email,read_stream";

                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "redirect", "<script>top.location.href='" +redirectstr +"'</script>");

                Response.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write(jsonObj["user_id"].ToString());
            }
```

Above code runs perfectly untill user press allow permissions.the application is actually redirecting to the mentioned redirect_uri http:... and not staying within facebook.

i am really bugged with this.let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is made this way so that it can be used by external sites which accept facebook login.

The redirect_uri can be set to:

```
apps.facebook.com/myapp/
```

or

```
www.facebook.com/pageurl?sk=app_YOUR_APP_ID
```

along with external site url.

Comment: does that mean i should give redirect_uri as my application url?

Comment: yes, you can set redirect_uri to apps.facebook.com/myapp or facebook.com/pageurl?sk=app_YOUR_APP_ID

Comment: doing that gives me unknown error,do i need to put same url somewhere else in facebook app configuration?

Comment: can you provide your oauth link?

Comment: it is https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID   &redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/myappname/&scope=email,read_stream

Comment: Sorry but I have to ask...
have you changed YOUR_APP_ID and myappname with your real values?
I believe it's safe to provide them since they are public.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8136/discussion-between-alexander-nenkov-and-mandar-jogalekar)